# Linear layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i want to have UI like this .[image]

I managed to do something to achieve this but i am not satisfied . I have pasted the image shows output of my code  .

> Please help me by improving my code or giving suggestions .

Mycode.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    tools:context="com.example.shipra.testing.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:weightSum="0.3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="POST ID:"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:textColor="#ababae"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="NEW12"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:id="@+id/postId_textview"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:weightSum="0.2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Pick Date:"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#ababae"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="16 Jan 2016"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:id="@+id/pickDate_textview"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="2 TRAILER of 22 tons"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
        android:id="@+id/layout5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.4">
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:weightSum="0.2"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:text="Vehicle Number"
            android:textColor="#3f464d"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:id="@+id/vehiclenumber_textview"
            android:text="Vehicle number"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:background="#dddddd"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout4"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:weightSum="0.2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Prefered Route"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="#3f464d"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="10sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:text="Route"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:id="@+id/route_textview"
                android:textColor="#3f464d"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:weightSum="0.2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Lowest Market Vehicle Rate"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="#3f464d"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textColor="#3f464d"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:weightSum="0.2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="Highest Market Load Rate"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="#3f464d"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:text="No load offer"
                android:textColor="#3f464d"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:weightSum="0.2">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Your Rate Per Ton"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:textColor="#3f464d"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:hint="@string/Rs"
                android:id="@+id/ruppee_textview"
                android:textSize="10sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="update"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout4"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout5"
        android:background="#dddddd"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

With the above code i am getting output :

[image]

Comment: I think the Portrait screen orientation might not work so well because the data requires a lot of width. Perhaps try reproducing the UI in landscape first - and you can use `layout_weight` to distribute the widths of each of the "columns" horizontally.

Comment: Try <Tablelayout> instead of linearlayout

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla : so you are saying that i should set orientation to landscape as portrait will not work  ?

Comment: @akhilRao : you think table layout will work in portrait screen ?

Comment: In order to properly organize the layout in portrait mode add horizontal <scrollView> tag as the parent of the layout and inside that tag add the above defined layout.

Comment: @akhilRao yes and if i add horizontal scroll view then i think i don't have to add table layout . Linear layout will work as well inside it . ISN'T ?

Comment: Yes if you add scrollview then no need of tablelayout,but if you add that layout then it looks well organized in single row

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
<HorizontalScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    tools:context="com.example.shipra.testing.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:weightSum="0.3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="POST ID:"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textColor="#ababae"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="NEW12"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:id="@+id/postId_textview"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:weightSum="0.2">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Pick Date:"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="#ababae"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="16 Jan 2016"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:id="@+id/pickDate_textview"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="2 TRAILER of 22 tons"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout2"
        android:id="@+id/layout5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.4">
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:background="#dddddd"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/layout3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:weightSum="0.2"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:text="Vehicle Number"
                android:textColor="#3f464d"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:id="@+id/vehiclenumber_textview"
                android:text="Vehicle number"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="7dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:background="#dddddd"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout4"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:weightSum="0.2">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Prefered Route"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:textColor="#3f464d"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="10sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:text="Route"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:id="@+id/route_textview"
                    android:textColor="#3f464d"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="63dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:weightSum="0.2">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Lowest Market Vehicle Rate"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:textColor="#3f464d"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="@string/text"
                    android:textColor="#3f464d"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:weightSum="0.2">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:text="Highest Market Load Rate"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:textColor="#3f464d"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                    android:text="No load offer"
                    android:textColor="#3f464d"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:weightSum="0.2">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="Your Rate Per Ton"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#3f464d"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:hint="@string/Rs"
                    android:id="@+id/ruppee_textview"
                    android:textSize="10sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:text="update"
                android:textSize="8sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout4"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout5"
        android:background="#dddddd"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Instead of Relativelayout you can define  TableLayout and you can replace LinearLayout with TableRow

Comment: I did but it still not coming that smooth . Nevertheless i play little bit with it . Hopefully will get the smooth layout